# Deleting consecutive and non-consecutive columns from a cell array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to delete multiple consecutive and non-consecutive columns from a 80-column, 1-row cell array `mycells`. My question is: what's the correct indexing of a vector of columns in Matlab?

What I tried to do is: `mycells(1,[4:6,8,9]) = []` in an attempt to remove columns 4 to 6, column 8 and 9. But I get the error: `A null assignment can have only one non-colon index.`

Comment: Since your cell array is a vector, `mycells([4:6,8,9]) = [];`  should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a colon for the first index. That way only the 2nd index is "non-colon". E.g.,

```
mycells(:,[4:6,8,9]) = []
```

MATLAB could have been smart enough to recognize that when there is only one row the 1 and : amount to the same thing and you will still get a rectangular array result, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the above *VERY VERY HELPFUL AND MUCH SIMPLER* answers, I ended up doing something more convoluted. As it worked in my case, I'll post it here for anyone in future:

1. So, I had a cell array vector, of which I wanted to drop specific cells. I created another cell array of the ones I wanted to remove:

`remcols = mycells(1,[4:6,8,9])`

2. Then I used the bellow function to overwrite onto `mycells` only those cells which are different between `remcols` and `mycells` (these were actually the cells I wanted to keep from `mycells`):

`mycells = setdiff(mycells,remcols)`

This is not neat at all but hopefully serves the purpose of someone somewhere in the world.